# enotez option backref with ebgaramond adds interline-spacing

Tags: endnotes, ebgaramond, enotez

When I load [`enotez`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enotez) and set the option `backref` with the font `garamond` (via [`ebgaramond`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond)), there is, for some reason, some extra space inserted between the line where the endnote-marker is placed and the preceding one.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backref]{enotez}
\setenotez{list-heading = \section*{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{\lipsum[1]}
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

These settings lead to the following output:

[image]

The extra interline-spacing does not occur when I disable the option `backref`:

[image]

When I use a different font (e.g. libertine), there are no problems either. Is it possible to remove the spacing without having to sacrifice the option `backref` or having to swap to a different font?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure really what the package is doing but looking for "backref" showed a suspicious looking box raise, and reducing the amount raised makes the log show baselineskip rather than lineskip spacing (so even baselines restored)

old:

```
....\glue(\baselineskip) 2.74857
....\hbox(7.7307+3.1755)x418.25555, glue set - 0.23798, direction TLT []
....\penalty 150
....\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
....\hbox(10.95+3.1755)x418.25555, glue set 147.7745fil, direction TLT []
....\penalty -300
```

new:

```
....\glue(\baselineskip) 2.74857
....\hbox(7.7307+3.1755)x418.25555, glue set - 0.23798, direction TLT []
....\penalty 150
....\glue(\baselineskip) 2.7157
....\hbox(7.7088+3.1755)x418.25555, glue set 147.7745fil, direction TLT []
....\penalty -300
```

example document

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\showoutput
\showboxdepth4
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backref]{enotez}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \enotez_write_mark:nn #1#2
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__enotez_hyperfootnotes_bool
      {
        \enotezwritemark { \hyperlink {enz.#1} { \enmarkstyle #2 } }
        \bool_if:NT \l__enotez_hyperbackref_bool
          {
            \box_move_up:nn {.5em} % was 1em
              { \hbox:n { \hypertarget {enz.#1.backref} { } } }
          }
      }
      { \enotezwritemark { \enmarkstyle #2 } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setenotez{list-heading = \section*{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\endnote{\lipsum[1]}
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record, I think this is the same problem reported at https://github.com/cgnieder/enotez/issues/42, in which case it should be fixed in the next release.